# condition for request does not work Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

The condition works in a strange way.
need request "A" if `true`, and request "B" if `false`.

```html
<input type='checkbox' :value='category.title' v-model='checkedCategories' @change='changeEvent'>
```

**js:**

```js
changeEvent($event) {
    if($event.target.checked) {
        this.forChange = true;
    } else {
        this.forChange = false;
    }
},
```

**requests**

```js
request() {
    if(this.forChange) {
        axios.get('link', {params: a, b, c })
    } else {
        axios.get('link', {params: a, c})
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

**upd:**
The condition starts to be triggered only after the third click. The first two give true

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the v-modeled `this.checkedCategories` instead of `this.forChange`?

Comment: @vanblart I can try. But I need to pass an array of selected checkboxes...

Comment: The way I'm handling multiple checkboxes in one of my apps is I have an empty array created in my `data` function, then v-model all of the checkboxes to that array, which then populates the array with any selected values. (As a side note, I'm also generating the checkboxes from a second array with all my values in it, but I don't believe that is necessary for this to work)

Comment: In your case, you should be able to array.length and %2 to determine an even or odd length (that's what it looks like you're doing in your last code block) and send the array from there.

Comment: @vanblart Unfortunately, checking with length doesn't work for me. Could you show an example with v-model?

Comment: Your code seems be ok: https://jsfiddle.net/alchemik1992/oar6vnb2/7/ Can you please provide a bigger part of your code? You can use a jsfiddle too.

Comment: @1_bug 
I created an example on jsfiddle with a comment on what is going on. https://jsfiddle.net/3n6bhkva/  The feeling that the array does not have time to update (?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `forChange` in your data section, and your checkbox should bind to the `checked` property, or the v-model.

Once you have the binding, you don't really need the method.

```js
<input type='checkbox' v-model='forChange'>
```

or

```js
<input type='checkbox' :checked='forChange' @change='forChange=$event.target.checked'>
```

Using both `:value` and `v-model` at the same time will cause issues, and is probably the root of your problem.